# Can't get all html page with Beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the content of this webpage : https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_rent/1-_beds/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-122.67022170019531%2C%22east%22%3A-122.19643629980469%2C%22south%22%3A37.615282466144976%2C%22north%22%3A37.93495488175342%7D%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A11%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22price%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3A872627%7D%2C%22beds%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A1%7D%2C%22fore%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22mp%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3A3000%7D%2C%22nc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fr%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22cmsn%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fsba%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D

I can't get all of it. Many elements are empty. I was told that it was the case because it was js code and bs4 can't read js and I had to use selenium instead, but I want to do it with bs4 and I know there is a way to do so. I also was told that it was the case, because I wasn't in the correct iframe, but I doesn't seem to be true. For example if you inspect one of the prices listed (e.g $2,200/mo) you will see that it is contained in a ul list and each apartment listed is a li element of that list. But when I scrape the page with bs it seems that most of these li elements are empty.
Also, bear in mind I'm a newbie in web-scraping and in python, so be cool please.
Thanks!

Here is the code I'm using to get the page html:

```
self.response = requests.get(url=URL, headers=headers)
self.html_doc = self.response.text
self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: This violates [Zillow's terms of use](https://www.zillow.com/z/corp/terms/): '**5. Prohibited Use.** BY USING THE SERVICES, YOU AGREE NOT TO… conduct automated queries (including screen and database scraping, spiders, robots, crawlers, bypassing “captcha” or similar precautions, or any other automated activity with the purpose of obtaining information from the Services) on the Services'. Please don't do that.

Comment: Oh... Didn't about that at all thanks for sharing Chris. So there is absolutely no way of doing what I'm trying to do without violating Zillow's terms? Is the issue really solely based on the fact that Zillow prevents users from web-scraping their website or is there something technical that i've done wrong? Just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @younesalaoui, I'm not a lawyer but I don't believe there's a way to scrape Zillow without running afoul of their terms of service. I haven't looked at their site but it is very likely that they are using JavaScript to populate the data you're looking for, as you mentioned in your question. The simplest technical solution is to use a tool that knows how to run that JavaScript, like Selenium.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks a lot for your answer Chris. Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this site use react. Check browser developer tool NETWORK on chorme or firefox and look how files and request make you browser. Check callstack and more request details pointing on data. I see on dt network this link [https://www.zillow.com/search/GetSearchPageState.htm?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-122.83501662207031%2C%22east%22%3A-122.03164137792969%2C%22south%22%3A37.548623602126355%2C%22north%22%3A38.00126648128239%7D%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A11%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22category%22%3A%22cat2%22%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22price%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3A872627%7D%2C%22beds%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A1%7D%2C%22isForSaleForeclosure%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22monthlyPayment%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3A3000%7D%2C%22isNewConstruction%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22isComingSoon%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22isForSaleByAgent%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22sortSelection%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22globalrelevanceex%22%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D&wants={%22cat2%22:[%22listResults%22,%22mapResults%22],%22cat1%22:[%22total%22]}&requestId=6](https://www.zillow.com/search/GetSearchPageState.htm?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-122.83501662207031%2C%22east%22%3A-122.03164137792969%2C%22south%22%3A37.548623602126355%2C%22north%22%3A38.00126648128239%7D%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A11%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22category%22%3A%22cat2%22%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22price%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3A872627%7D%2C%22beds%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A1%7D%2C%22isForSaleForeclosure%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22monthlyPayment%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3A3000%7D%2C%22isNewConstruction%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22isComingSoon%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22isForSaleByAgent%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22sortSelection%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22globalrelevanceex%22%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D&wants=%7B%22cat2%22:%5B%22listResults%22,%22mapResults%22%5D,%22cat1%22:%5B%22total%22%5D%7D&requestId=6). React builds the site page based on this data. Sry my english not good but i hope i helped.

Comment: Well thank you for your kind response, but I really don't get it and the problem is not your english haha, it's my web dev knowledge. I don't see how checking the network tab (which I didn't even know existed btw...) will help me with that issue. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You need certain data, don't you? So there is absolutely all the data that your browser gets from the site. I emphasize again ALL THE DATA! Since the react builds the page from the data c API, you can see where they are formed and how. And if you go to my link, there are addresses of prices, etc. at home just need to parse this JSON.

Comment: okay but how did you get that JSON? And I sitll dont get it. in your JSON there is almost nothing???? Where do you see the prices? Again i'm real newbie...

Comment: I check browser network tools and see requests with this json. If i join on my finded link i finded on json this info:***
{"zpid":2067021133,"streetAddress":"13900 San Pablo Ave #20","zipcode":"94806","city":"San Pablo","state":"CA","latitude":37.96114,"longitude":-122.34152,"price":86000.0,"bathrooms":1.0,"bedrooms":1.0,"livingArea":520.0,"homeType":"MANUFACTURED","homeStatus":"FOR_SALE","daysOnZillow":-1,"isFeatured":false,"shouldHighlight":false,"listing_sub_type":{"is_FSBO":true},"isUnmappable":false,"isPreforeclosureAuction":false,"homeStatusForHDP":"FOR_SALE","priceForHDP":86000.0...***